# How to declare a variable in Try and access it in Catch?

Tags: c++

I am creating an object of my class in try/catch block and want to access it in catch block in case of exception. Even if the object is created ok, I cannot access it in catch block as it declared outside the block.

```
 try {
    MyObject ob(arg1,arg2); //this can trow exception

    ob.func1(); //this also can throw exception

} catch (std::exception& ex){
    //I want to access ob here if it was constructed properly and get the reason why func1() failed
}
```

I can use nested try/catch blocks to solve this issue but is there any other way to solve this

```
try {
    MyObject ob(arg1,arg2); //this can trow exception
    try {

        ob.func1(); //this also can throw exception
    } catch(std::exception& ex) {
        //object was constructed ok, so I can access reason/state why the operation failed
    }
} catch (std::exception& ex){
    //object failed to construct
}
```

Comment: Do you have an empty constructor? Maybe create default instance outside, and set the values inside and see if it throws an exception? But can we see this constructor at least

Comment: How will you know the construction wasn't the one that threw the exception?

Comment: if its caught in outer catch then object construction threw exception, else execution will go to inner try/catch

Comment: An object cannot be accessed outside of its scope. Try using a pointer that is initially null

Comment: @AndyG, someone just got downvoted to the ground for this suggestion.

Comment: why the downvotes for the question?

Comment: SergeyA Right but maybe @AndyG could show us what he exactly means

Comment: So as to why you can't do this... When an exception is thrown, the stack is unwound - calling destructors for the stack variables as it goes. Any object constructed on the stack in the scope of the try{} block (and any nested scopes) are destroyed. The reason the pointer solution works is because the pointer is declared outside the scope.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not do this. It is not possible to access this variable from same-level  catch block.

The solution is to stop using exceptions as a flow control mechanism - they are not - and use them  as  they are, an indication of exceptional  situation - in  which case it doesn't really matter  what did throw.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot access an object out of scope. But to answer this:

> get the reason why func1() failed

If the object construction failed because of an exception, this means that the std::exception already contains some information about why it has failed.
So you have to do this in your code:

```
catch (std::exception& ex){
    // object failed to construct
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. It raises an important point about the validity of the OP's reason for asking the question. They wanted an object from the `try` scope to be available in the `catch` scope so that they could probe it for information about why something failed on it. But, aside from the fact that mechanistically that's not possible - it doesn't make sense either, because such info should be provided by the exception. This both explains that what they wanted can't be done and provides a superior alternative. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Andrei Alexandrescu's ScopeGuard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjTrfoiB0MQ) might help here:

```
try {
    MyObject ob(arg1,arg2);

    SCOPE_FAIL { /* Handler 1 */ };

    ob.func1();

} catch (std::exception& ex) {
    /* Handler 2 */
}
```

The body of `SCOPE_FAIL` will be executed if its scope is left via stack unwinding, that is, an exception has been thrown. Unfortunately you can't access the exception itself there, but you can access `ob`.

The rest of the program behaves as usual, so the execution looks like:

1. `ob` is successfully constructed;
2. `ob.func1()` is executed and throws;
3. `/* Handler 1 */` is executed;
4. `ob` is destructed;
5. `/* Handler 2 */` is executed.